# Custom Inerited Note Field 255 character limit and no HTML for Editing?

Tags: content-type, field-definition

Two issues I have with the same column type.

Using Sharepoint 2010.

I created a custom Content Type (for use as news articles content Type) and added a couple of custom columns. I have a issue with a column which is used as a ArticleIntro (Intro into a Article). The definition for the field is as follow:

```
<Field Type="Note" DisplayName="ArticleIntro" Required="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" NumLines="6" RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="Compatible" Sortable="FALSE" Group="News Article Columns" ID="{b4f32c74-c296-4956-aa5a-bc2db0a02117}" SourceID="{8327f4e7-83bd-4f9d-8147-4c107bad405d}" StaticName="ArticleIntro" Name="ArticleIntro" ></Field>
```

My issue with the column is as follow: 
1. Why can I not have more than 255 characters (i've seen multiple answers when googling but not a definitive one)
2. When editing a Item which was created using my News Article Content Type, the Field is supposed to show a Rich Text Editor so that users can use some HTML such as Bullets, Fonts, Links ect in the column.It however only shows a Normal Textbox. How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use  **UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="TRUE"** attribute to enable more than 255 characters on a note field.

But if you want more than 255 characters on your note field with rich text capabilities - why don't you just use an HTML field?